Child prodigy (idiot savant) that writes numbers in a book
What's the name of this TV show about a little boy (named Max I think) Who's 11 yrs old and doesn't speak but he writes down numbers in this book he has? He never stops writing them and his dad fights to protect him. Because he's like a prodigy.
At the beginning he ran away from school when it was raining and went on top of and electrical tower and to write numbers and also at the last episode I remember watching is that they were doing text on Max and his friend who was a girl just like him who had got kidnapped on a company to do text on her. I think her name was Amelia in the TV show and her mother died trying to save Amelia and Max.
I watched like a year ago on Netflix in 2012(?) and it was from the U.S. 
What is the name of this TV show?

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all?

I'm pretty sure that you are looking for Touch, although the childs name is Jake, not Max.  Other than that it maintains your recollections of his fascination with numbers and what happened with Amelia.
